# Simple LaTeX document sticks all consecutive words together (ignoring spaces) both inside and outside of `\text`

Tags: spacing, amsmath, white-space

```
\listfiles\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont
Let $a$ be a symbol.
\end{document}
```

The result is:

> Let $a$ beasymbol.

I'm not sure how to not ignore spaces in the document.

---

The
 problem persists with `article` instead of `standalone`.  It also persists with no extra packages specified.

---

Okay, I found where the problem is.  It's in loading the SVG into Qt, because it works for all of you and it works when I load the .svg file produced directly into Chrome.  When I load the same .svg file into my app, I get the spaces culled.  Any ideas?  50 points if you can guess what's wrong... :P

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps try updating your packages and if the problem persists, add `\listfiles` to the preamble and post the version of the packages here.  Also try removing packages and see if the problems remains -- that may help to locate the source of the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill I added `\listfiles` and it didn't generate any .dvi so I put the log above

Comment: @PeterGrill I tried removing all packages and the problem persists

Comment: Did you see if any packages need updating?  The `\listfiles` output should be in your console/log.  Please update the question with the minimum number of packages to reproduce the problem. Also, perhaps try using the `article` class and see if problem persists.

Comment: You added `\listfiles` directly after `\documentclass` which is wrong, it should go before it

Comment: I see that you updated the question, but you still include all the packages. If the problem can be reproduced with less packages that may help to locate the source of the problem.

Comment: It looks like the LaTeX format file on your system may be out of sync with the TeX executable. (I would have expected a LaTeX format dated ca May 2018, not Apr 2017.)  Please update your MikTeX distribution, rebuild the format files (esp. the LaTeX format), and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Off-topic: Since the `amsmath` package loads the `amstext` package automatically, and since the `amssymb` package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically, the third `\usepackage` statement in your preamble could be written much more succinctly as `\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}`.

Comment: @EnjoysMath I've no problem with TeXLive 2018 on Linux.

Comment: Tried on Overleaf v1, Overleaf v2, MiKTeX 2.9 (up-to-date). There are no problems.

Comment: @JouleV knowing that, what is going wrong?

Comment: You are creating a dvi, how are you viewing it? Or converting it to pdf? Are you completly sure that you really viewing the actual output the compilation? E.g. if you change a to x, do you see the x?

Comment: +1 to the previous comment; here's a test following up: Can you change the text to “Let $x$ be another symbol”, recompile the file, and post into the question a *screenshot* of the output?

Comment: You say that the problem persists even with article and no other packages.  Can you update your example and log to just that case?  That log file is much shorter.  Does it also persist if you remove the font commands?

Comment: @Teepeemm I know for certain the problem exists with either latex.exe or dvisvgm so there's no need to reproduce it or w/e you guys were hinting.  My program reproduces it every time you place an object, so constantly, or whenever you edit a label.

Comment: @Teepeemm I will remove the font commands and post the code

Comment: Here is the required post on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689272/qt5-qgraphicssvgitem-ignores-svg-text-spacing

Comment: If `latex latex_input` -> latex_input.dvi or `pdflatex latex_input` -> latex_input.pdf compile correctly and it's just dvisvgm that's messing up, it's probably off topic on this site (and would have been something for you to check originally).  I feel like between this question and your (?) posting on SO, there's almost enough for someone to understand what you're asking.  But I don't know that I'd say either one has enough information on its own.

Comment: When you say “the result is...” everyone understood it as meaning the result from TeX (the DVI or PDF file) and now it turns out that those are actually fine, and the issue is not even in the SVG file (produced by dvisvgm, nowhere mentioned in the question), but in some other (unmentioned) application that seems to have trouble with fonts in SVG files. In fact until the latest edit, the question didn't even mention “SVG”. While I'm glad your problem appears to be solved now, I think omitting crucial information like this is a cruel waste of people's time. :-)